# android should I change the location of my sdk?

Tags: android, android-studio

I just download android studio, set it up and installed everything from the sdk.

i noticed now that my sdk location is on this path: `c:\users\myname\appdata\...` that location is hidden, so i have to show the hidden folders to access it.

should I move that folder to inside the `android studio` folder?

and what should I do in order to tell the android studio that the sdk folder has been changed, or the android studio will know that itself? and promote me to set the new location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like easier manual access to the files of the SDK, yes you should change it. Just move it to a location you prefer and when you launch android Studio it will notice that the default SDK location has been destroyed, so it will ask you to tell it where the SDK is, just tell it the location of the SDK.

Comment: can I location the sdk inside the android studio folder?

Comment: as an extra note to @endlesschaos good answer, DO NOT move to inside AndroidStudio. AS recently moved it to out of the folder due to issues with auto-updating and calculating checksums. Put it somewhere else.

Comment: @Budius i have `Android` folder inside my `programs files`, and inside it there is `Android studio` folder, can I add the `sdk` as a direct son to `Android` folder? so `sdk` and `andriod studio` will be brothers

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Yes. brothers it's fine, it doesn't matter. Just not inside `/android studio/`

Comment: plus one, i will accept the answer when the system allows